# virsh "Operation not supported: Cannot use direct socket mode if no URI is set"

Tags: qemu, virsh

Env: MacOS Arm64

Installed:

```
sudo port install virt-manager
```

Trying to create a default network following [this](https://blog.programster.org/kvm-missing-default-network)

When I do this:

```
sudo virsh net-define --file default.xml
```

I get this:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Operation not supported: Cannot use direct socket mode if no URI is set
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem while trying to run the FCOS on my Fedora laptop for the very first time.

Solution for Fedora-based system:

`sudo dnf install libvirt`

I would assume Ubuntu would accept:

`sudo apt-get install libvirt`

Regards!

Comment: In my case libvirt was already installed but the daemon was not started. Make sure libvirt is properly installed using this solution and make sure it is started using `sudo systemctl enable --now libvirtd` ... as i aws following this procedure https://serverfault.com/questions/434064/correct-way-to-move-kvm-vm

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this message and fixed it by adding `uri_default = "qemu:///session"` to /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf

Of course the solution will be different if you're using a different hypervisor other than qemu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).